# import data and Looping for the file

Tags: matlab, loops

My purpose is to split the string into part then check whether the 'f11_data' contain those split word. if yes then return 0, if no then return 1. I have 100 strings, but it doesn't make sense to type the str/needles 100 inside my code times. How do I use looping to do that? I'm facing a problem using `importdata`.

```
str1      = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hostname';
str2      = 'http://hello/world/hello';
str3      = 'http://hello/asd/wee';

f11_data1 = 'hostname From wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Jump to: navigation, search In    computer networking, a hostname (archaically nodename .....';
f11_data2 = 'hell';
f11_data3 = 'hello .....';

needles1  = strcat('\<', regexpi(str1,'[:/.]*','split'), '\>') 
needles2  = strcat('\<', regexpi(str2,'[:/.]*','split'), '\>') 
needles3  = strcat('\<', regexpi(str3,'[:/.]*','split'), '\>') 

~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(f11_data1, needles1, 'once'))
~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(f11_data2, needles2, 'once'))
~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(f11_data3, needles3, 'once'))
```

This is how I modified the above code using a loop:

```
 data = importdata('URL')
 needles  = regexp(data,'[:/.]*','split') %// note the different search string

 for i = 1:2

 A11_data = needles{i};
 data2 = importdata(strcat('f11_data', int2str(i)));
 %feature11_data=(~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(data2, needles, 'once')))
 %feature11(i)=feature11_data
 ~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(data2, needles, 'once'))
 end
```

I get the error :
    "
    ??? Error using ==> regexpi
    All cells for regexpi must be strings.

```
Error in ==> f11_test2 at 14
~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(haystack, needles, 'once')) "
```

Comment: What is inside `f11_data1` and `f11_data2`? Is `data2` a string?

Comment: f11_data1, f11_data2, f11_data3 is haystack1, haystack2, haystack3 respectively, while URL.txt contain str1, str2, str3

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to do but, if you want to do something equivalent,

```
for i = 1:3
    str = importdata(URL_LIST[i])
    needle  = strcat('\<', regexp(str,'[:/.]*','split'), '\>');

    haystack = importdata(HAYSTACK_LIST[i]);
    ~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(haystack, needle, 'once'))
end
```

Obviously you need to define `URL_LIST` and `HAYSTACK_LIST`.

Comment: My purpose is to split the string into part then check whether the 'f11_data' contain those split word. if yes then return 0, if no then return 1.

Comment: yes so you need to modify the above code so that it import your url list and f11_data.

Comment: I would like to try with 1 data first, there is a different between importdata & "str='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hostname';" I can split my data into 1x6cells when using "str      = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hostname';", but i cnt split my data into 1x6cells, it show me 1x1cells when using importdata. Any ideas?